# how I make object value as key of another object of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm getting data in form of array of objects like this...

```
 let array = [{serviceId:2,name:'ahsan'}, {serviceId:5,name:'majeed'}, 
              {serviceId:2,name:'john'}, {serviceId:5,name:'ziyad'}];
```

I want this this array in this form please anyone help...

```
 let arrayIWant = [
                    { 
                      2:[{serviceId:2,name:'ahsan'},{serviceId:2,name:'john'}], 
                      5:[{serviceId:5,name:'majeed'},{serviceId:5,name:'ziyad'}]
                    } 
                  ]
```

Please help

Comment: Can you post your approach (code)?

Comment: @Ele I'm getting data from firebase realtime db and and push them in array like the first one array. Now i want to create a new array which have one object and inner that object we separate those object which have same serviceId and make the serviceId value as key of that object and push same serviceId object in that key as array like in the second code snippet

Comment: We understood what you want, however, we need a little effort from you.

Comment: @Ele What effort i can do?

Comment: Simply, we don't code for people, we help people with the problems in their own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this to get your expected result

```
    const array = [{serviceId:2,name:'ahsan'}, {serviceId:5,name:'majeed'}, 
                  {serviceId:2,name:'john'}, {serviceId:5,name:'ziyad'}];
    const iteratedArray = array.reduce((acc,val) => {
      const key = val.serviceId;
       if (!acc[key]) acc[key] = [];
       acc[key].push(val);
       return acc; 
    },{});
    const arrayIWant = [iteratedArray];
    console.log(arrayIWant);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate through all the items in the array.
2. For each item:

   - If the `serviceId` does not exist as a prop of the object, set the prop's `serviceId` key with an array containing the item.
   - If it exists, add the item to that array.

Comment: Hi sir Could you please share the code snippet as i'm new to javascript

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to group the array of objects by the `serviceId`.
To do this you can either use groupBy method from lodash https://lodash.com/docs/#groupBy

or write your own implementation like this:

```js
var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

var data = [{serviceId:2,name:'ahsan'}, {serviceId:5,name:'majeed'}, 
          {serviceId:2,name:'john'}, {serviceId:5,name:'ziyad'}];
console.log(groupBy(data, 'serviceId'));
```

I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash library's _.keyBy method

_.keyBy(array, 'serviceId');

```
const _ = require('lodash')
let array = [{serviceId:2,name:'ahsan'}, {serviceId:5,name:'majeed'}, 
              {serviceId:2,name:'john'}, {serviceId:5,name:'ziyad'}];

result = _.keyBy(array, 'serviceId');

console.log([result])
```

check this out. It should give you the desired result.